# Time delay for a loop in Swift XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timedelay

I'm a fairly new coder which is trying to push my limits, I'm trying to make an adventure capalist clone. If you're not too familiar it's practically just a tycoon game in the form of a UI. Anyways I've gotten stuck on how to get the money to multiple every few seconds.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cash: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var applePrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tomatoPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var berryPrice: UILabel!
    
    var cashTotal = 100
    var appletotal = 5
    var berrytotal = 10
    var tomatoTotal = 15
    var applemultiplier = 1
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func buyapple(_ sender: Any) {
        if cashTotal >= appletotal {
            cashTotal = cashTotal - tomatoTotal
            applemultiplier = applemultiplier + 1
            appletotal = appletotal * applemultiplier
            cash.text = "Cash: \(cashTotal)"
            applePrice.text = "Price: \(appletotal)"
        }

        while 0 == 0 {
            sleep(20)
            cashTotal = 5 * applemultiplier
            cash.text = "\(cashTotal)"
        
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buyberry(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func buytomato(_ sender: Any) {     
    }  
}
```

Comment: You ***absolutely*** do not want to use `sleep(20)`. Read up on [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great project to learn from, and you're asking a good question. As others have said, you'll want to use a timer to update your game state periodically. Add a property to your view controller (or whatever class manages the game):

```
var gameTimer : Timer
```

and set it up when your game starts:

```
let updateInterval = 20.0
gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: updateInterval, repeats: true) { timer in
    updateGameState()
}
```

Finally, add a function to actually do the updating:

```
func updateGameState() {
    // your update code here
}
```

(You could do the updating right in the closure that the timer runs, but it's good style to break it out into its own function.)

Now the timer will run `updateGameState()` every `updateInterval` seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your question to explain what you mean by "...how to get the money to multiple every few seconds".

It looks like you want to increase the value in your `cashTotal` variable every 20 seconds.

You currently use `sleep()`. Don't ever use `sleep()` on the main thread of an interactive app. It causes your entire UI to freeze, and will likely cause the system to think your app has crashed and kill it.

You want to create a repeating `Timer`. Take a look at the `Timer` class reference, and in particular the method `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`. That will let you create a repeating timer that fires every X seconds, and invokes the code in a closure that you provide.

Your current code, in addition to being used in a never-ending while loop (bad) with a sleep command (bad), also sets `cashTotal = 5 * applemultiplier`

If applemultiplier never changes, then that code will set `cashTotal` to the same value every time it fires.

Don't you really want to **add** some amount to `cashTotal` every time the timer fires? If you multiply it by an amount greater than one, you'll get exponential growth, which you probably don't want. (Say you have 10 dollars. Every 20 seconds you multiply that by 2. After 2 minutes (6 doublings) you'll have 10x2⁶, or 640 dollars. After 10 minutes (30 doublings) you'll have 10*2³⁰, or almost 11 **billion** dollars.)

Comment: *Don't you really want to add...* Probably not. Investments tend to grow exponentially, not linearly. If you start with $1000 and it grows at 10% annually, you're *multiplying* your initial investment by 110%, or 1.1, each year. So the first year your total increases by $100, but the second year it's $1100*1.1 or $110, the third it's $1210*1.1 or $121, and so on. This is why the rich get richer. If you could manage 200% growth every 20 seconds, you'd do extremely well, but those opportunities are hard to find.

Comment: *If you multiply it by an amount greater than zero...* Pretty sure you mean one, here, not zero. Multiplying by a value between zero and one reduces your total. It's still exponential, but it's negative growth, and I don't think you meant that.

Comment: Caleb, you're right. I did mean to say "if you multiply by an amount greater than **one**." Exponential shrinking would be pretty odd. Thanks for catching that. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're right. This is probably compounding interest.